# not redirecting correct if user has permission

Tags: php, codeigniter

In my **user group** I have set up where I can check or unchecked each controller name and then click on submit and send the names to the database. In text/array format. And those controllers I would have access to otherwise should if try to access that controller that was unchecked would get **redirected** to `'admin/error_permission'`

Each user also has the user group id next to the user id.

How am I able to get the names of my controllers from database and then have them redirect to my error page like so

table name: 
**user_group: columns: user_group_id, name, permission**

The name of column where controller names are stored is permission
and controller names are stored like this **permission** `a:2:{s:6:"access";a:1:{i:0;s:11:"column_left";}s:6:"modify";a:1:{i:0;s:11:"column_left";}}`

**Rather than write each controller name in the array how can I get the ones from database.**

```
function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
    if ( ! $this->session->userdata('logged_in'))
    { 
        // Allow some methods names from the database permission?
        $allowed = array(

        );
        if ( ! in_array($this->router->fetch_method(), $allowed)
        {
            // Not Allowed Access
            redirect('admin/error_permission');
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That looks like PHP [serialized arrays and objects](http://php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php). If Codeigniter stored those, it hopefully has a simple method to call them back individually. Getting particulars out of MySQL accurately with a query would be quite difficult. It really needs to be entirely retrieved by PHP then `unserialized()`'d and Codeigniter must have a documented way.

Comment: Oh boy. You can't get individual key or values from permission without unserializing = the db can't help you, you have to query & unserialize, lookup the name. This is odd. Saving data in serialized form is very inefficient from a database design standpoint (unless it's a no-sql database, which love json.). The data should have been stored in separate tables reflecting their internal structure. This would allow easy queries.

Comment: Do you have any examples of unserializing to be able to get what I am after

Comment: Yes, i've added it as an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$permissions = 'a:2:{s:6:"access";a:1:{i:0;s:11:"column_left";}s:6:"modify";a:1:{i:0;s:11:"column_left";}}';
$permissions_array = unserialize($permissions);

var_dump($permissions_array);
```

Outputs:

```
array(2) {
  'access' =>
  array(1) {
    [0] =>
    string(11) "column_left"
  }
  'modify' =>
  array(1) {
    [0] =>
    string(11) "column_left"
  }
}
```

---

```
if (false === array_key_exists($this->router->fetch_method(), $permissions_array))
{
            // Not Allowed Access
            redirect('admin/error_permission');
}
```

Comment: OK and what model query should use?

Comment: pseudo SQL: `SELECT permission FROM user_group WHERE user_group_id = $user[user_group_id] AND name = $controllerName;` . If you have the time, then try to get rid of the serialized permission field. Do a database normalization. This allows for more efficient queries.